# How to catch absolutely all exceptions / errors

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, error-handling

I have a windows service application, running under WinXPe, which sometimes fails with an error and displays an message box to the user:

> "The instruction at “”
>   referenced memory at “0x00000000”. The
>   memory could not be “read.” Press OK
>   to exit the program

If the user clicks "Ok" the service is restarting.

I have tried to catch all unhandled exceptions with registering a eventhandler at `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`
in the handler I log the exception details and exit the application.
But the error I mentioned above is NOT handled from "UnhandledException".

The application is heavily multi threaded, using System.Threading.Timer and System.Threading.Thread. And it's using some third party libs, one of these libs are using native interop, I have no source of the native lib.

I tried to point out the error with an debugger attached, but the error doesn't show up ;)
The application has to run several days before the error occurs.

I need a way to handle such a error.

Thanks

Comment: Matti is correct that this is not a managed exception, so your usual debugging techniques won't work. Are you using P/Invoke to call down to any native methods? Are you using any third-party libraries that are written in unmanaged code? We really need more details to be able to solve this problem. If you want to try debugging the problem yourself, you have to enable native code debugging.

Comment: I have no way to fix anything in the native lib. I have no source. It's a component of a PC based PLC "TwinCat". There must be some way to handle this :(

Comment: I suppose [my option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920154/how-to-catch-absolutely-all-exceptions-errors/5920184#5920184) should work well **[with a separate AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.load.aspx)**. For absolute isolation, use the native lib from a separate process using [.NET remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.71).aspx). Another obvious road to take is _report a bug to the [library creators/maintainers](http://www.beckhoff.com/english/support/default.htm)_

Comment: TwinCat's native code, running on another thread, bombs with an AccessViolation.  You cannot recover from this, a restart is required.  Contacting Beckhoff about it is pointless, this code hasn't been updated in over 12 years.  Ditch it if you can't live with it, I'm sure your customer can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Vectored Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681420%28VS.85%29.aspx)

This is part of windows [SEH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679270%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ([Structured Exception Handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_Exception_Handling#Structured_Exception_Handling)) and IIRC here is precious few errors that you could not at least be notified of in such  a case.

You *will* probably want to write any handling code directly to the native WIN32 API (in unsafe/unmanaged code) and using pre-allocated (static?) buffers only, because there will be many things unreliable at that moment in time.

Beware of/stay away from threading, locking primitives, memory allocations, disk IO; preferrably use Windows default API's to, e.g. restart the process or produce a minidump and things like that

Comment: I assume you missed the part where the program is written in C# for the .NET Framework?

Comment: @Cody: I assume you missed the question itself? If it was not a problem, there wouldn't be question. Also `"And it's using some third party libs, one of these libs are using native interop"`

Comment: But since I have no access to the native source, I think I can't apply this. Or have I missed something?

Comment: @chriszero: I wouldn't know by which token you cannot. It is explicitely possible to register a vectored handler from a dynamically (un)loaded DLL, there is nothing you cannot detect. Perhaps there is not much you can do to 'save' things, but I imagine you can have a separate thread for a separate AppDomain and just declare that a total loss, and instantiate a new thread for the same purpose. TRWTF is having to workaround unstable code. You might want to use WinDbg/a memchecker to see what usage pattern causes the crash

Answer (score 3):

That error is not a managed exception. It's a lower level memory access violation. Essentially a NULL pointer access in native code.

This is something you're supposed to be completely protect from in managed code, so it's likely one of your native libraries or the way you're using them. If the error only appears after a few days of execution, you might be best off first going through any native library calls, checking their signatures and making sure you pass them data that makes sense.

Comment: Yup. But if you could be using unmanaged code somewhere, you can still have this. This 'problem' is encouraged by many libraries with unmanaged code (dependencies), and the rise of plugin/IoC idioms, that ironically _resulted from the rise of managed platforms_). If there is any concern about reliabity/security you should at all times _require_ in your application that all loaded assemblies be strong-named, verifiable and not requiring Full Trust. Only then, I would cautiously agree with Matti's statement that you need not really worry about things like this

Comment: But which options I have to handle this?

Comment: @chriszero: I'm... afraid we'll have to wait for a person who knows Windows better for that.